# Can I change instance's assignment from inline function?

Tags: android, kotlin

I made an inline function downsizing bitmap and create another.

```
private fun Bitmap.limitSizeTo(maxSize: Int): Bitmap {
    var width = this.width
    var height = this.height

    val bitmapRatio = width.toFloat() / height.toFloat()
    if (bitmapRatio > 1) {
        width = maxSize
        height = (width / bitmapRatio).toInt()
    } else {
        height = maxSize
        width = (height * bitmapRatio).toInt()
    }
    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(this, width, height, true)
}
```

As is:

```
var resizedBitmap = bitmap.limitSizeTo(100)
doSomething(resizedBitmap)
```

To be:

```
bitmap.limitSizeTo(100)
doSomething(bitmap)
```

What I tried, but not compiling is:

```
private fun Bitmap.limitSizeTo(maxSize: Int): Bitmap {
    var width = this.width
    var height = this.height

    val bitmapRatio = width.toFloat() / height.toFloat()
    if (bitmapRatio > 1) {
        width = maxSize
        height = (width / bitmapRatio).toInt()
    } else {
        height = maxSize
        width = (height * bitmapRatio).toInt()
    }
    this = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(this, width, height, true)
}
```

I think 'to be' code is more cool, is it?
Anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

No this not possible and not desirable anyway IMO. You cannot change the receiver of an extension function like this, the best possible way is to simply return a new, edited, immutable instance. Just as you did in the first place:

```
val resizedBitmap = bitmap.limitSizeTo(100)
doSomething(resizedBitmap)
```